# Detect App lock using button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using this code in the react native for appState and i am permforming some actions on this

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
        return () => {
            AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
            setRow(false)
        }
```

This code is working as expected. But when i am doing lock my phone manually this event also fires that i don't want. So how can i restrict this code. That it will work in background mode as it. But do not work in the device lock function. On device lock manually by button click i can perform some other action.

Answer (score 0):

`AppState` will always fire when locking your screen because the app state will change to `background`, but there's a workaround using dates you check this article on how to archive it from [here](https://dev.to/shtabnoy/react-native-appstate-a-workaround-to-detect-screen-lock-26cm).

I know it's late but I hope it helps someone searching for it in the future.